# Mule Properties Window not showing

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I have update Mule Anypoint Studio, But the Mule Properties Window is not showing. It is Showing Message **"Select a Mule component to edit its Properties"**. Even I have selected the Mule Component it is not showing any Properties to edit. I found the question of similar properties but not found any help in below link:

http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/mule_properties_editor

I have downloaded the new Anypoint studio but the problem remains the same. Please help me out.
[image]

Comment: Still having this issue 8 years later. Amazed how buggy Mule is

Answer (score 3):

Edit AnypointStudio.ini

```
--launcher.GTK_version
3.24
```

**-- substitute "3.24" specific to your machine --**

Example:
On Ubuntu

```
 dpkg -l libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you open the Error log and check what is in there ? 
Window > Show View > Other > Error Log

I guess there should be an exception or something logged.

A couple of questions that might help travelshoot your issue: 
- Anypoint Studio installation directory path 
- Varsion of Java 
- Version of Windows, 64 bits ?

Answer (score 0):

for what I have seen this seems to be a problem with the 5.2.0 Release Candidate.

Can you please try to do a fresh download of the latest 5.2.0 Studio release? 
https://www.mulesoft.com/ty/dl/studio